# PostgreSQL UNIQUE constraint not being applied on Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, constraints, unique-constraint

The following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  phone_number VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Isn't causing `username` to have the `UNIQUE` constraint.

```
my_db=# \d users
                                    Table "public.users"
    Column    |          Type          |                     Modifiers
--------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer                | not null default nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 username     | character varying(50)  | not null
 password     | character varying(100) | not null
 first_name   | character varying(50)  | not null
 last_name    | character varying(50)  | not null
 address      | character varying(255) | not null
 phone_number | character varying(20)  | not null
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

---

**Question**

I haven't found any limitations to `UNIQUE` in the documentation. What am I missing?

**Context**

PostgreSQL running on the official [PostgreSQL Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)

Comment: works here. Maybe the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ` interfered and you had an older version present?

Comment: @wildplasser That isn't the problem. But that made me think I needed to __rebuild my postgres docker container__ in order to see the constraints added. This would create a new image with the changes I made (the added `UNIQUE` constraint). Merely stopping and re-running the container didn't apply my changes to the existing image. I'd accept a formal answer if you post one. And thank you.

Comment: Works for me. My hypothesis is that the command is not being run because the table exists (without the unique constraint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@wildplasser and @dmg are correct, the `IF NOT EXISTS` part would not override the existing table and the changes wouldn't be applied. So dropping that would fix the problem *on a non containerized database instance*.

On the present issue, I had to rebuild my container (create a new image) with the new SQL script (that added the `UNIQUE` constraint). That solved the problem.

Merely stopping and re-running a Docker container doesn't apply the SQL script. On the [official PostgreSQL Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), *the init SQL script runs upon image creation* (aka `docker build`).

So for every change in the SQL script, I had to run `docker build my_db_container` to get rid of the old image and have a new one.

Thanks all for the comments that gave me direction to find the solution.

Comment: `to get rid of the old image` means: lose all the data currently present in the table?

Comment: @wildplasser not if you store the data in a [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/), separate from the database container. `docker-compose` makes it trivial to set one up and link it to the database container.

Comment: As a DBA, or as the owner of the data, I would want to be sure about that, before even attempting such steps.

Comment: @wildplasser For sure. I made multiple tests after posting this question. The data indeed persists after the container is gone. The one catch is that a volume might be hard-linked to an image. So if an image changes, the volume won't work anymore. But the data remains. You can connect it to another container and extract the data.